# "C++ compiler works....no" when compiling mongo-cxx-driver legacy using scons

Tags: mongodb, gcc, g++, scons

I'm getting a `C++ compiler works....no` error when compiling the **CPP legacy driver**.

I'm compiling with:

```
scons --64  --cxx=/usr/local/bin/gcc   -cc=/usr/local/bin/gcc  --prefix=/opt/mongo  install
```

The **config.log** states:

```
libmpc.so.2 cannot open shared object file

libmpc.so.2 does exists in /usr/local/lib which is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

When I execute the compilation command for `conftest_o.cpp` file, from the config.log it compiles with no issues.

```
~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile seems fine.
```

OS: RedHat 6.6 64bit

GCC: 4.9.2

mongodb CPP legacy driver version: 1.0.5

Boost : 1.57

Python: 2.6.6

scons: 2.3.6

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does `file libmpc.so.2` say? Can you run the compiler manually, or does it only fail under `configure`?

Comment: You should install a C++ compiler using `yum`

Comment: Is libmpc.so.2 a symlink which points to a file which isn't there?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using gcc and not g++ as C++ compiler?

Comment: libmpc points to a file that does exist. C++ compiler is installed. Scons runs it's own config, it checks if compilation even works by compiling: int main() { return 0; } The code is in conftest_0.cpp The config.log states that /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries : libmpc.so.2 cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory .

When I copy the compile command from the log and execute it manually, it compiles with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Update : solved the problem using 
--propagate-shell-environment flag when running scons. 
Apparently scons does not pass shell environment variables to child processes.
Thanks for your help